# My wireframe mode isn't working

Tags: wireframe

So I don't know what happened, but whenever I go into wireframe mode this happens[image: This is a portion of the entire object and is only showing this single frame or slice from any view I look at it from. I don't know what i did or how to fix it. Can someone help me out here please]

Comment: Looking at the very large numbers of verts, edges and faces in the top left of that image, I'd guess that the object is so dense at that scale that it looks as if it's in solid view! What happens if you zoom in with the mouse wheel? You also haven't got an object selected at the moment which won't help.

Comment: Whenever I zoom in it stays the same. It also looks at the same splice from any angle and doesn't show the rest of the objects. This just started happening too because wireframe normally was working and now it's not. I think I pressed something accidentally but I'm not sure of what i could've pressed. Even with an object selected it still stays in this type of view thing

Comment: Maybe you have accidently hidden the other geometry? For show/hide functionality look here https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/show_hide.html

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: My file is too large to share honestly, and the other objects aren't hidden, they're all on the screen. The panel shown is just what wireframe mode is showing. There's much more on screen but whenever I go into wireframe, it only shows that little piece